# Finding $n$ scalars such that $\det{(cI-A)}=0$ without eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

My problem is this

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}$.  Prove there are at most $n$ distinct scalars $c\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $\det{(cI-A)}=0.$

I know that the determinant is an $n$-linear function and I was thinking the argument had something to do with that.  Then I began to thing that because it's $n$-linear I can facter out a particular constant from each row, but I'm not sure this argument holds any water so to speak.  What should be my starting point?  Should I assume there are more than $n$ distinct scalars?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the multilinearity of the determinant function to prove that $\det(xI-A)$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial in $x$.